# Using C++14 on Linux and shipping binaries targeting different Linux releases

Tags: linux, c++11, gcc, c++14

I’m developing a cross-platform server software using C++14 and I want to be able to ship it as a binary to different versions of Windows and Linux. For Windows have I created a binary with all dependencies statically linked. I successfully been able to install and run this binary on all versions of Windows Server.

How can I generate a binary for Red Hat Enterprise Linux that can run on RHEL6.4 or later?

To get support for C++14 on Linux, it seems I would need to use version 5 or later of GCC? No version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux seems to be delivered with a GCC version that support C++14? If I have understood it correctly, I need to use Red Hat Developer Toolset 4.1.0 to get a GCC version that supports C++14?

Red Hat Developer Toolset 4.1.0 seems to only supports RHEL6.5 and later, but I can live with that. So if I use Red Hat Developer Toolset 4.1.0 and compile my software on RHEL6.5, how should I link it?

When reading the Developer Toolset 4.1.0 documentation it seems to exist an ABI compatibility issue and Red Hat recommends the use of -std=c++98 for production software development? Does this mean I can’t use C++14 and create a binary that can run on different Linux version, even within the same type of distribution?

Any help on clarifying this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should be able to static link every library on Linux into your program, just like Windows. If that doesn't work, you can always ship the binary with the required dependencies.

Comment: Note: static linking can create license compliance problems if LGPL software is involved.

Comment: I always wondered that. Years ago you had to either release the source to be compiled locally or literally release one binary for every version of every distro if you wanted it to work, but nowadays you see software like TeamSpeak 3 Server where a single binary is compatible with "Linux" no matter which one. I'm not much of a Linux person so I don't know what changed to make that possible, but apparently they convened a way.

Comment: As I've provided a concrete approach to doing this below, and there are no other answers, would you mind either commenting on my answer with any additional questions you may have that i can clarify, or accept my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you what is done for the product that I help develop.

We build our own versions of GCC and binutils on every UNIX/linux distribution that we are targeting for release, and build our sources with that. We also vendor in to our sources all C++ libraries on which we depend (like boost, etc.). Finally, we statically link libstdc++ from our custom toolchain.

The result is that we have binaries that only depend on the C interface associated with each specific linux distribution, which lets us use whatever version of the C++ standard that we want during development.

We then publish packages and binary tarballs for each distribution.

We also build a "generic" version (built, as always, with our custom toolchain) on a very old linux system, and with many features disabled so that we don't pick up dependencies on the required/supporting system libraries. That version depends on very few system libraries beyond libc and libpthread, so can be run on almost any linux distro that ships with the libc minimum.